# PayPal - What does "each receiver" in guest payment mean?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I'm using Adaptive Payments - Delayed Chained Payment. For the payment solution without PayPal account the buyer uses Guest Payment and in documentation they say:

> Each receiver of a guest payment must be a verified PayPal business
>   or premier account holder.
>   https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/

What does the "each receiver" actually means? Does it mean that even the secondary receiver in Delayed Chained Payment must be veryfied business or premier account holder? There is no way to test this in sandbox environment, because it works even if the primary receiver is personal account.

I understand it in a way that my application is business account holder so that the Guest Payment should work. For the 2nd transaction to send the money to the secondary receiver I'm not using Guest Payment, I simply call *ExecutePayment* method from Adaptive Payments API. Will it work if the secondary receiver in this case is normal personal account?

Comment: Technically, if it's working a particular way in the sandbox it should work that exact same way when you go live.  If you want to confirm you could submit a ticket to [PayPal MTS](http://www.paypal.com/mts/) and they can give you more details about if anything would be different.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I've already submitted a ticket to PayPal MTS as you've suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal MTS answer:

Does it mean that even the secondary receiver in Delayed Chained Payment must be verified business or premier account holder?

The answer is YES, in all cases.